# SQL query where filter = *

Tags: php, sql, filter, where-clause

Writing a small filter in PHP/sql.
User selects from two filter options, however they also have the option to choose "all" in the filter basically just making the query not filter that result.

Using the basic WHERE method the query looks like this

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = '$userid' AND department = '$department'");
```

How would I adapt this to make the filter return all results for that particular filter? as writing a bunch of if else statements in the php seems bulky.

Comment: Use Switch statement - php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php‎

Answer (score 1):

```
$expected_filters = array(
  // 'mysql_column'=>'php_variable',
  'userid'=>'userid',
  'department'=>'department',
);


$final_filters = array();

foreach ($expected_filters as $k => $v) {
  if (isset($_POST[$v]) && trim($_POST[$v])) {
    $final_filters[] = sprintf("%s= '%s'", $k, $v);      
  }    
}

$where = '';

if (count($final_filters)>0) {
    $where = implode(' AND ', $filter);
    $where = ' WHERE ' . $where;
}

$query = ("SELECT * FROM user $where");
```